# OpenCV 3.1.0 - LNK1104 with opencv_world310d.lib (Visual Studio Express 2013)

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013, windows-7-x64, opencv3.1

iam actually trying to get opencv running on my Computer. I allready configured the environment variables on Windows and added the Path for the includes and the libraries in a propertiesheet.

Now when i want to add additional dependencies i watched into my directory (opencv\build\x64\vs12\lib)and there are only two files. opencv_world310.lib and opencv_world310d.lib. So they are on my HDD.

I think these are the files i have to add?

I did this and then i got the error LNK1104 could not open "opencv_world310d.lib. Same with opencv_world310.lib.

Iam trying to build a example-code from opencv so there should be everything fine with it. I saw some Tutorials they did not have any issue. But they used OpenCv3.0

Is there any workaround?

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes. By default, opencv_world310.lib is the only file you should link with.
Or if you're building with Debug configuration, you should use opencv_world310d.lib instead.

Since the error code is LNK1104, I believe your additional library path is something wrong.

And then please check you are building x64 code not win32 code.

Comment: $(OPENCV_DIR\lib  <- Visual Studio additional library path;
C:\DEV\opencv\build\x64\vc12 <- OPENCV_DIR environment variable;
%OPENCV_DIR%\bin <- Path;   Iam building on Debug x64.

Comment: Then you need only world310d.lib. It looks your lib setting is OK.
Yet, there is no ending parenthesis for $(OPENCV_DIR, is that just a copy-and-paste error? Also you can try absolute path for now, try C:\DEV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib instead of $(OPENCV_DIR\lib for additional lib directory.

Comment: Hey. I fixed it. I dont know if there is a issue with using propertiesheets. I deleted them from my projectfolder and configured the projectproperties. Now it works but only when i use the direct path for the INCLUDE directory. The lib path is fine. Thanks alot!